# Retrofit : listview in fragment

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Tabs with three fragments.
Im trying to load some data in fragment (TwoFragment) by using retrofit 2. 
but I'm getting
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        final ListView listView=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listviewupgradeTo);

        LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class,"abc","123");
        Call<List<UpgradeInfo>> call=loginService.getListInfo(i);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UpgradeInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UpgradeInfo>> call, Response<List<UpgradeInfo>> response) {
                List<UpgradeInfo> list=response.body();
                listView.setAdapter(new UpgrageInfoRecordListViewAdapter(getContext(),list));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UpgradeInfo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: First of all, you don't really have to set adapter and create a list onResponse .. Just make a private variable in class, and when you get the response notify adapter about changes. 

Second of all, what is the problem ? crash / not working as expected ?

Comment: *Im trying to fetching data in fragment by using retrofir2* - and then what happened? what is your **question**?

Comment: the problem is null pointer exception ,

Answer (score 0):

You should always perform null checks when receiving models from a connection. You should also check if the response is valid. Finally, the list is not the body of the response model itslef. It is contained IN the body.
Like so:

```
if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) { // make this first check
    List<UpgradeInfo> list=response.body().getUpgradeInfo(); // here, you should get the list from within the model
    if (list != null) { // make the null check
        listView.setAdapter(new 
UpgrageInfoRecordListViewAdapter(getContext(),list));
    }
}
```

Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: what is getUpgradeInfo() ? where  i should write it?

Comment: It's a method you create inside the Response model. You can name it whatever you want. It's just an example. The point is that you get the List from inside the response's body. The List is not the body itself.
Why don't you take a look at the Retrofit documentation: http://square.github.io/retrofit/   . You may also want to check Future Studio's tutorials. They're pretty good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4XU8yPzSx0